# Why does React see object as a string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and stuck trying to render an array using any sort of iteration...

Outputting the variable and its `typeof` to console looks okay:

```
export function ComponentDetail({ id }: IProps) {
    ...  // get object from API/database
    console.log(tags);
    console.log(typeof tags);  
}
```

[image]

The problem is when I go to employ this variable to render its elements, I'm told it's a string, it won't compile, the app breaks.

[image]

This is probably something simple, but it's driving a React n00b like me who can do this with VanillaJS in his sleep nuts.

A few more details:

- The data is coming from MongoDB via GraphQL service.
- The tags attribute is an array in both MongoDB and GraphQL (according to their their built in web query interfaces).
- `JSON.parse(tags)` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0`. It seems it's already a string at the time this get's executed (see above the first element starts with "d").

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: Chrome is parsing your array totally fine but your React code sees it as a string. Try by wrapping your array from the response in `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Adding to a previous comment, if your API is returning json and you are using `fetch`, [use response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: You use Typescript, thus you need to check how this variable declared. It seems in runtime it is an array, but in compile time it's a string.

Comment: I added some details above regarding suggestions.

Comment: With this small sample, its difficult to assess. Check your Network logs to see whats being returned on your call.

Comment: you seem to be confusing *compile*-time and *run*-time - as you've already shown, at runtime `tags` is an array (therefore the error when trying to call `JSON.parse` on it). At compile-time, though, it is a string - either your types are incorrect or insufficient for TS to infer the type of `tags` correctly. Check the signature of the function that assigns the value to `tags` initially.

Comment: @OlegValter this was indeed it. I had the `tags` attribute of the `Component` interface (used by the object I was returning) set to `string`.  Changing it to `string[]` resolved the issue.  Which of course, makes perfect sense! Go ahead and submit the answer if you like. Otherwise, I'll offer this change as the answer when I can.

Comment: @conner.xyz - it happens :) Better to close the question as a typo, though, as it indeed is one (+ Николай Гольцев was the first one to outline the actual problem)

Comment: @OlegValter I don't see the option to close as a typo. It's not worth it to make others to find this if they run into a similar situation?

Comment: @conner.xyz - I meant voting to close, sorry for the confusion - I am used to considering these issues as typoes that you would've likely figured out a bit later regardless (btw, feel free to add the info in question/answer if it remains unclosed). In any case, the info about the actual issue should be visible in our discussion for quite a while (your upvoted comment is likely to stay).